# How to include schema inf while using dblink in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-schema

All

I am trying to use dblink in PostgreSQL to run query on different databases. The following works if the table "user" is under the public schema:

```
select * from dblink(
'hostaddr=1.2.3.4 port=5434 dbname=dbname user=username password=password',
'select id from user')
       as t1(
       id bigint
);
```

However, I need to run the query on some other defined schemas. Does anyone know how to add the schema information in the above query? I can't figure it out from the PostgreSQL docs.

Answer (score 1):

When you write SQL query like

```
SELECT id FROM user
```

PostgreSQL will resolve table name like `user` into fully qualified name like `schema.tablename` using [schema search path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-schemas.html), which by default is set to `"$user",public`.

In other words, `user` will resolve into `public.user` unless you tweaked server configuration.

However, you can specify schema explicitly in your statement, like this:

```
SELECT id FROM otherschema.user
```